# How to send text to the search field through Selenium and Python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, css-selectors

I am trying to pass arguments to a search text in a HTML code using Selenium in Python:

I am working on the following HTML code:

```
</form><form class="search-box-inner">
    <div class="input-container">
        <input type="text" class="typeahead search-box-input left" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Search ratings, research, analysts, and more..." maxlength="900"></div>
</form>
```

The code does not have id or name. It has elements by class only.

I tried the following

```
self.driver.find_elements_by_class_name('search-box-inner').send_keys("HSBC Bank plc")
```

But I am getting the following error:

> ```
> AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'send_keys'
> ```

Then I tried to fetch first element of the list and send keys by using the following code:

```
self.driver.find_elements_by_class_name('search-box-inner')[0].send_keys("HSBC Bank plc")
```

I get the following error:

> ```
> "selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: cannot focus element"
> ```

I have tried both the above methods for "typeahead search-box-input left" class as well. it throws the same error. following is the code I used for this:

```
self.driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[@class='typeahead search-box-input left']").send_keys("HSBC Bank plc")
```

I again got the following error:

> ```
> AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'send_keys'
> ```

Then I tried to fetch the first element of the list with the following code:

```
self.driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[@class='typeahead search-box-input left']").[0].send_keys("HSBC Bank plc")
```

I again got the following error:

> ```
> selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotVisibleException: Message:
> element not interactable
> ```

I also tried the following way:

```
element = wait.until(Ec.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//*[@placeholder='Search ratings, research, analysts, and more...']")))
```

But could not sent the argument/keys to the search bar.
Any suggestions will be really helpful.

Comment: sorry but you putted in your HTML, the input filed is class="typeahead search-box-input left", if you want select class="search-box-inner" after you have to get its 2 child

Comment: Hi Carlo, I tried with this class as well "typeahead search-box-input left", but still it didn't work.

Comment: very strange... are u able to add an ID and try again? otherwise select the father object and print it to see what u get, then select the child and try again to print what u have until u get the text field ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`find_elements_by_xpath` returns a list of webelement so that is the reason you cant use the `send_keys` method directly on that. You need to use `find_element_by_xpath` or `find_elements_by_xpath("xpathExpression")[0]` if you need to use `send_keys` on the element.

Please try the below suggestions to solve your problem:

1. Try the xpath `self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='input-container']")` instead of the xpath you are using.
2. Even after using the above `xpath` if you get `ElementNotVisibleException` then please check if the element is in iframe, if yes, then switch to the iframe and then use `send_keys` on the element.

   To switch to iframe you can use the property [`selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver.WebDriver.switch_to`](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver.WebDriver.switch_to): `driver.switch_to.frame(driver.find_element_by_tag_name('iframe'))` and then `send_keys` on the element using the mentioned xpath and if you want to switch back to the default content, you can use `driver.switch_to.default_content()`

Comment: Thanks Sameer. I tried this way, although I was able to get the webelement but I was not able to pass any keys to it. It was again giving me "ElementNotVisibleException". Then I checked if the element is in frame, but that is also not the case. Please let me know if I am missing something at my end. Thanks.

Comment: And try to put some wait before fetching the element, should work fine then.

Comment: @NidhiArora did you check with the new xpath, did it work ?

Comment: Done :) Thanks!

Comment: @NidhiArora How did you solve this? I am facing the same problem. I am able to get the webelement but I was not able to pass any keys to it. Even it is not in the iframe. Also included time.sleep(5) before fetching the element

Answer (score 1):

Why not use a css selector e.g.

```
.find_element_by_css_selector(".search-box-input").send_keys
```

You could extend the selector, for example, with:

```
.search-box-input[placeholder^='Search ratings']
```

Answer (score 1):

### I would use this stretch:

```
    #Importing libs
    from selenium import webdriver
    from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
    
    #Look for the class
    search_box = driver.find_element_by_class_name("typeahead search-box-input left")
    
    #Write what we be searched#
    search_box.send_keys('What will be searched')

    #Submit the text
    search_box.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
```

Answer (score 0):

As per the HTML you have provided it is pretty clear that there are multiple `<form>` nodes present within the [HTML DOM](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom.asp).

---

### Analizing the errors

- First attempt: `self.driver.find_elements_by_class_name('search-box-inner')` would return a **List** so you can't invoke `send_keys()` and you see the error as `AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'send_keys'`
- Second attempt: `self.driver.find_elements_by_class_name('search-box-inner')[0]` will identify the `<form>` node which can't be in **focus** so you can't invoke `send_keys()` and you see the error as `WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: cannot focus element"`
- Third attempt: `self.driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[@class='typeahead search-box-input left']")` would again return a **List** so you can't invoke `send_keys()` and you see the error as `AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'send_keys'`
- Forth attempt: `self.driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[@class='typeahead search-box-input left']").[0]` wasn't a valid [Locator Strategy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890)

---

### Solution

To pass a *character sequence* to desired element you can use either of the following solution:

- Using `CSS_SELECTOR`:

  ```
  self.driver.find_element_by_css_selector("form.search-box-inner input.typeahead.search-box-input.left[placeholder^='Search ratings']").send_keys("HSBC Bank plc")
  ```
- Using `XPATH`:

  ```
  self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("//form[@class='search-box-inner']//input[@class='typeahead search-box-input left' and starts-with(@placeholder, 'Search ratings')]").send_keys("HSBC Bank plc")
  ```